# Two concurrent request were able to lock the same row in Postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, concurrency, c3p0

**when two concurrent request were made for the below code, both of the requests were able to acquire lock simultaneously and hence were able to execute the block of code**

Sample code running in production:

Sample Code for reference :

```
//Starting point for the request
@Override
    public void receiveTransferItems(String argumet1, String refernceId, List<Item> items, long messageId)
            throws Exception {
        ParentDTO parent = DAO.lockByReferenceid(referenceId);
        if (parent == null) {
            throw new Exception(referenceId + "does not exist");
        }

        updateData(parent);

        for (Item item : items) {
            receiveItem(td, td.getWarehouseId(), item.getItemSKU(), item.getItemStatus(), item.getQtyReceived(), messageId);
        }

    }
    
    
    private void updateData(ParentDTO td) throws DropShipException {

        //perform some logical processing and then execute update 
        DAO.update(td);
    }
    
    
    
     private void receiveItem(ParentDTO td, String warehouseId, String asin, String itemStatus, int quantity, long messageId)
            throws Exception {
    
        /**
         * perform some logical processing
         * 
         **/
        //call is being made to another class to do the rest of the processing
        service.receive(td, asin, quantity, condition, container, messageId);
    }
```

```
@Override
    public void receive(
            ParentDTO parentDTO,
            String asin,
            int quantity,
            Condition condition,
            Container container,
            long messageId,
            DataAccessor accessor) throws Exception {



        List<ChildDTO> childDTOs =
            DAO.lockChildDTOItems(parentDTO.getReferenceId(), asin, condition,
                                                  CostInfoSource.MANIFEST);

        List<ChildDTO> filterItems = DAO
            .loadChildDTOItems(parentDTO.getReferenceId(), asin, condition.name());

        long totalExpectedQuantity = getTotalExpectedQuantity(filterItems);
        long totalReceivedQuantity = getTotalReceivedQuantity(filterItems);

        int quantityNormalReceived = 0;
        for (ChildDTO tdi : childDTOs) {
        
            int quantityReceived = 0;
            if (asinDropShipMsgAction != null) {
                quantity -= asinDropShipMsgAction.getInitialQuantity();
                quantityNormalReceived += asinDropShipMsgAction.getInitialQuantity();
            } else {
                quantityReceived = new DBOperationRunner<Integer>(accessor.getSessionManager()) {
                    @Override
                    protected Integer doWorkAndReturn() throws Exception {
                        return normalReceive(tdi, quantityLeft, container, MessageActionType.TS_IN, messageId);
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
          
        }

    }
    
    
    
    private int normalReceive(final ChildDTO childDTO,
                              int quantity,
                              final Container container,
                              final MessageActionType type,
                              long messageId)
        throws Exception {

        /**
         * perform some business logic
         * 
         * */
         
        DAO.update(childDTO);
        return someQuantity;
    }
```

Implementation for lockByReferenceId function:

```
@Override
    public ParentDTO lockByReferenceId(String referenceId) {
        Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ParentDTO.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("referenceId", referenceId)).setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT);
        return (ParentDTO) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Implementation of DBOperationRunner class :

```
public T execute() throws Exception {
        T t = null;
        Session originalSession = (Session) ThreadLocalContext.get(ThreadLocalContext.CURRENT_SESSION);
        try {
            ThreadLocalContext.put(ThreadLocalContext.CURRENT_SESSION, sessionManager.getCurrentSession());
            sessionManager.beginTransaction();
            t = doWorkAndReturn();
            sessionManager.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                sessionManager.rollback();
            } catch (Throwable t1) {
                logger.error("failed to rollback", t1);
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            ThreadLocalContext.put(ThreadLocalContext.CURRENT_SESSION, originalSession);
        }

        return t;
    }
```

Recently i observed one issue in production code in which two or more simultaneous requests were able to acquire lock on the same data at same time.
I am using hibernate and criteria as a DB framework and c3p0 as a connection pooling framework and Postgres as DB.
Note : This issue is intermittent and only observed for some random concurrent requests which is making it hard to debug.

I am unable to understand how two concurrent request were able to lock the same rows simultaneously. Can you please help me in identifying what is going wrong in this case?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: "*which two or more simultaneous requests were able to acquire lock on the same data at same time*" - that's not possible. If I had to guess: your code doesn't use transactions the way you think it does.

Comment: With out the actual SQL statements and application code this is not answerable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name according to me, the probable reason behind this can be the session level advisory locks which works on session level instead of transaction level. When two threads were trying to take lock on same row most probably somehow both the requests managed to obtain the same connection object from the connection pool and hence were able to execute the request simultaneously. 

P.S. I cannot share the code due to confidentiality issues.

Comment: You did not mention that you are using advisory locks - although I am surprised that you can get them to work through Hibernate. You also mentioned you are UPDATEing the rows which will not not acquire an advisory lock.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you see any issue in using advisory locks in hibernate? Actually the code I am working on is around more than 1.5 years old and was written by some one else and I am just trying to find out the problem as to what is going wrong ?

Comment: I am just surprise that you could convince Hibernate to use that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Can you explain your last comment in detail?

Comment: Advisory locks are a PostgreSQL specific concept. You have to write raw SQL to use them. It is not suited for an abstraction layer. Anyway, without seeing the actual SQL statements, this is unanswerable, because we can only guess what actually happens.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   I have added the sample code using which will help you in understanding the transaction management at application level.

Comment: I don't see any @Transactional annotations or the reference to a TransactionManager which are required if you want to use transactions in Hibernate (or JPA).  And what does  `DAO.lockByReferenceid()` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  We use DBOperationRunner class which manages the transaction for us. I have added the sample implementation for it.